# Remove category from pagination

Tags: php

I'm trying to modify a old theme but im getting stuck on this code

```
$post_type = 'portfolio' == get_post_type() ? 'portfolio' : 'post';

if ( ! themify_check( "setting-{$post_type}_nav_disable" ) ) :

    $in_same_cat = themify_check( "setting-{$post_type}_nav_same_cat" )? true: false;
    $this_taxonomy = 'post' == get_post_type() ? 'category' : get_post_type() . '-category';
    $previous = get_previous_post_link( '<span class="prev">%link</span>', '<span class="arrow">' . _x( '&laquo;', 'Previous entry link arrow','themify') . '</span> %title', $in_same_cat, '', $this_taxonomy );
    $next = get_next_post_link( '<span class="next">%link</span>', '<span class="arrow">' . _x( '&raquo;', 'Next entry link arrow','themify') . '</span> %title', $in_same_cat, '', $this_taxonomy );

    if ( ! empty( $previous ) || ! empty( $next ) ) : ?>

        <div class="post-nav clearfix">
            <?php echo $previous; ?>
            <?php echo $next; ?>
        </div>
        <!-- /.post-nav -->

    <?php endif; // empty previous or next

endif; // check setting nav disable
```

This part specifically. Currently it is listing all of my articles but I cant figure out how to list only category id `1` `2` `3`

```
$this_taxonomy = 'post' == get_post_type() ? 'category' : get_post_type() . '-category';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong line. `$this_taxonomy` is telling what taxonomy type (category, tag, custom tax, etc.) to look for, not what actual term in that taxonomy type.

That being said, you should look at `$previous` and `$next`. More specifically, `get_previous_post_link()` and `get_next_post_link()`. The fourth parameter is `$excluded_terms` which is currently empty.

The codex says you can supply an array or comma-separated list of term ids.

This would seem cumbersome to maintain because you would have to update that parameter each time a new term is added to your taxonomy.

But technically, if you have categories `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` and `5`, then supplying `$excluded_terms = '4,5';` to your previous and next function would exclude those terms from your list.

So, if you want a method that won't need updating each time a new category is added, I would try to do it by modifying the main query instead. *Add this to your `functions.php`*

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_allowed_cats' );
function my_allowed_cats( $query ){

  $post_type = get_post_type();

  if( $post_type == 'post' || $post_type == 'portfolio' ){

    // Use category ids
    $allowed_cats = array(
      1,
      2,
      3,
    );

    $query->set( 'category__in', $allowed_cats );

  }

}
```

This is untested, but it should work